# Offer is mentioned, but not yet received. Is it appropriate to ask for a faster response?

Tags: job-offer

I am applying for jobs in multiple companies. Over the past month I had 3 talks with company A (one recruiter, one head of department, and one technical lead). After these talks I received a mail saying theyall were very enthousiastic, and would like to make me an offer. To do this, they requested a description of my current salary and benefits. I have sent these informations. This is now almost a week ago.

Meanwhile, I have received an OK offer with company B after two meetings. I'm highly suspecting Company A could have a better offer, and might have a more interesting day-to-day job. However, I won't bore you further with the pros and cons of both companies.

Company B needs an answer somewhere next week, since I'm their best candidate but not the only one, and obviously they don't want to lose the others in case I decline late.

I would like to know if it's appropriate to ask company A to 'hurry up', since I would like to make a more informed decision on the standing job offer. Also, in what way can I best approach this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tell Company A that you have an offer in writing from another company, and need to respond in a week. I've done the same in many occasions. Usually it has worked for me, and no one seemed offended, if that's your concern. Provided you are polite and professional, no one should be offended.

However, if Company A is a big company (e.g., of international scale), it may not be possible for them to get the offer to you sooner. Sometimes the offer needs to be signed by busy execs who are traveling or on holiday (vacation). Sometimes hiring decisions are made by committees, and you have to wait for their next meeting. This sort of thing is frustrating, of course.

Comment: Good answer. I have been in the same position and simply called Company A back and asked for a status and mentioned how excited I was about the company but I did have a pending offer from another company. That goosed the HR person to contact the manager and I had an offer within a day and ended up accepting that position since it was a much better off.